# Is there a network for music generation software like apple logic?

Tags: discussion, software

Is there a network for music generation software like apple logic or other daw?

I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: Are you referring to another Stack Exchange site, or something else?  Use of music software is on topic here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site includes music generation and editing software within scope, along with DJ tools and many others.

As long as you have a question about music practice or performance, please feel free to ask it here. Specific tags will help you see existing questions, or you can browse the list of questions for wider guidance.